# How to setup for Stereoscoic rendering in modern OpenGL?

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader, stereoscopy

I am used to old style OpenGL 2.0, in which setting up for stereoscopic rendering was simple like:

1. Select back left buffer using glDrawBuffer (GL_BACK_LEFT);
2. Setup the frustum for the left eye using glMatrixMode() and glFrustum()
3. Rendering geometry for Left eye view.
4. Repeat steps 1 to 3 for right eye view.

Since there are no more glMatrixMode() or glFrustum() functions in modern OpenGL, can anyone can explain stereo setup using OpenGL shaders? What will be the sequence of events to setup left and right eye views? Note that I am assuming that the GPU supports quad buffer stereo. Thank you.

Comment: @datenwolf but there are shaders involved too... so do we call shader program id twice, once for left and right eye each? This seem a bit wasteful. Is there a better way to setup for stereo when Shaders are involved?

Answer (score 0):

The only difference is, that with modern OpenGL the matrix stuff has been relegated to 3rd party code; either matrix operations implemented by yourself, or a library. Practically every matrix math library aimed at computer graphics will have a function to set up a frustum transformation.

So instead of matrix mode and glFrustum you use that.